# How to configure webproxy settings to bypass hosts and networks in the shell?

Tags: terminal, mac, proxy

[image]

Can I manage this setting in the Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure proxy settings in the shell use the command *networksetup*.

To get help enter `networksetup -help`.

To bypass networks, hosts and domains use the command:

```
sudo networksetup -setproxybypassdomains <networkservice> <domain1> [domain2] [...]
```

The default items in the list are **.local* and *169.254/16*.

So if you want to add a domain (*abc.com*) and a host (*17.12.3.5*) but keep current items in the list use (example network service: en1 - to get a list of network services enter: `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`):

```
sudo networksetup -setproxybypassdomains en1 *.local 169.254/16 abc.com 17.12.3.5
```

To clear the list use:

```
sudo networksetup -setproxybypassdomains en1 Empty
```